# WPF BindingExpression path error

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, binding-expressions

I have model `BaseModel` with fields as `Id`, `Created`, `Deleted` and `Name` etc.

From this model I have derived models `Category` and `Brand`. Model `Brand` has field `Image`.

Also I have class `Node` (Title as Name and Value as all object)

```
public class Node : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _title;
    private BaseModelDto _value;
    private bool _isSelected;

    #region ctor

    public Node(string title, BaseModelDto value)
    {
        Title = title;
        Value = value;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            _title = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }

    public BaseModelDto Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

I use class `Node` for `ComboBox`. So I have ComboBox for Category and for Brand. Cause Category and Brand are derived from BaseModel I use for them same class `Node`

In `<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>` I want to display `Image` if it exists. So I wrote next code:

```
<Image MaxHeight="30" Margin="15,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="ImageCheckBox" Grid.Column="1">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding Value.Image.FileLocation, Converter={StaticResource ImagePathConverter}}" />
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

It works, it displays images only for `Brand` items, cause only they have `Image`.

But in output window I see next message:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Image' property not found on 'object' ''Category' (HashCode=56044044)'. BindingExpression:Path=Value.Image.FileLocation; DataItem='Node' (HashCode=65381042); target element is 'Image' (Name='ImageCheckBox'); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')

As I read before, any exception in Binding can have influence on WPF App performance. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: if it's not a `Brand` what should be displayed? A text? Nothing? A default image?

Comment: Well, does the object `Category` have an `Image` property?

Comment: @SteffenWinkler, if none, then nothing

Comment: @ChrisF, `Category` doesn't have `Image` property

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `ItemTemplateSelector` of the `ComboBox` to something like this:

```
public class CategoryBrandItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate CategoryItemTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate BrandItemTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if(item is Category)
            return CategoryItemTemplate;

        if(item is Brand)
            return BrandItemTemplate;

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

In XAML:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <local:CategoryBrandItemTemplateSelector BrandItemTemplate="{StaticResource BrandTemplate}"
                                                 CategoryItemTemplate="{StaticResource CategoryTemplate}" />
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
</ComboBox>
```

Where `BrandTemplate` is a `DataTemplate` resource declared somewhere (this will be the same that you are now using as the `ItemTemplate`) and the `CategoryTemplate` will be the one without the `Image` and the failing binding.